# How to navigate from ViewModel to a Fragment in Android Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a view model I have added a click event listener. How do I navigate from that ViewModel into a Fragment

The ViewModel Code

```
class PromoAdapter(var promo: ArrayList<PromoModal>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PromoAdapter.UserViewHolder>() {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(promo[position])
        holder.promoRow.setOnClickListener() {
            // Navigate to Fragment with name UserFragment
           
        };
    }
}
```

User Fragment Code

```
class UserFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View? {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(container!!.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.user_page_fragment, container, false)
   }
}
```

I have tried writing the following code still not working

Inside the ViewModel Click Event

```
val intent = Intent(itemView.context, UserFragment::class.java)
itemView.context?.startActivity(intent)
```

I cant find something working any help will be appreciated

Comment: In the question you have mentioned that the click event is coded inside the ViewModel but I don't see the ViewModel here. Did you try it to add in the `Adapter`?

Comment: `PromoAdapter` is an adapter, not a view model. Using the wrong name for it will no doubt confuse potential answerers.

Comment: you should rewrite the question, you show code of an recyclerview adapter but ask about the Viewmodel which is other concept in Android and Architecture. If you want to send the event to fragment from adapter you may use listeners or cast from the context as a fragment .

Answer (score 2):

It's better to move the click listener to a fragment

In Adapter:

```
class PromoAdapter(
    var promo: ArrayList<PromoModal>,
    val openFragment: (promoModal: PromoModal) -> Unit
  ) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PromoAdapter.UserViewHolder>() {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(promo[position])

        val currentItem = promo.getOrNull(position) ?: return

        holder.promoRow.setOnClickListener {
            openFragment(currentItem)
           
        };
    }
}
```

In Fragment:

```
val mAdapter = PromoAdapter(
     promo = promoList,
     openFragment = { promoModal ->
          // Navigate to Fragment with name UserFragment 
     }
   )
```